# SetState is being updated in the call back function but the component is not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a function for onclick where I am setting the state back to the old value which I am getting it from props. As shown below:

```
<EditOrChangePassword
    isVisible={this.state.personalInformationEditModeIsOn}
    onClick={() => this.setState({
             name: this.props.customerName,
            personalInformationEditModeIsOn: !this.state.personalInformationEditModeIsOn,
            }, () => {
              console.log(this.state);
           })}
 >Cancel</EditOrChangePassword>
```

The state getting in the console is updated one. And even the 'personalInformationEditModeIsOn' is also being updated and the UI changes according to it. But the value of name is not being changed. For the onchange function of the input box I am writing function as below.

```
validateName(value: string) {
    this.setState({
        name: value,
        nameValidationMessage: ''
    });
}
```

I couldn't what is the problem with name in the state. Can some one help me out!

**Update**

This is the code which has onchange event:

```
<TextBoxContainer>
                        <TextBox
                            placeholder="First Name"
                            value={this.state.name}
                            onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
                                this.validateName(e.target.value)}
                            disabled={!this.state.personalInformationEditModeIsOn}
                            invalidMessage={this.state.nameValidationMessage}
                        />
                    </TextBoxContainer>
```

This is the validateName function:

```
validateName(value: string) {
    this.setState({
        name: value,
        nameValidationMessage: ''
    });

    if (value.length === 0) {
        this.setState({
            nameValidationMessage: 'Name Cannot be Empty.'
        });
    } else if (value.length < 3) {
        this.setState({
            nameValidationMessage: 'Name should be more than 2 characters.'
        });
    }
}
```

This is the state which I am using is initialized using constructor:

```
constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        personalInformationEditModeIsOn: false,
        emailIdEditModeIsOn: false,
        name: '',
        email: '',
        emailValidationMessage: '',
        nameValidationMessage: '',
        isChangePWDialogBoxOpen: false
    };
}
```

Comment: Have you checked with React Dev Tools to see if the correct component state is changed?

Comment: Is `validateName` firing? How are you calling it?

Comment: Depending on how you attach `validateName` function to the `onChange` event, `this` may not be what you think it is. Other then that, I don't see anything wrong with the code that you have provided.

Comment: It means whereever the component has name in state exists that value might change, are you saying that? @boxmein

Comment: I am calling as onChange={(event)=>this.validateName(event.target.value)} and its being fired

Comment: That looks fine, but I don't think enough code is provided. I see you're setting a name state on some component in which we don't know. And you have a `validateName` event attached to I'm assuming a textfield, which I assume is inside `EditOrChangePassword` component. So what it looks like to me is you have 2 different components, both that has a `name` state. If that's correct, then you're `setState` is only going to update the state of one component.

Comment: Ohhhh! Having same name in two components state have effects like these? I am not aware of that. Thank you for your info.

Comment: To be clear you can have `name` in the state of two different components, but the state is not shared. If you have a child/parent component relationship where the parent needs to know the state of its child. Then it is better to "lift" the state up to the parent, and control the child using props. The react docs talks about this here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: If that answers your question, then you should write an answer to your own question. If not, then you should provide more details about code. Include all components involved with the issue, including the relevant parts of their render functions and anything that you have tried.

Comment: But here this whole thing in one component  I am getting customerName from parent component using props itself.

Comment: I see, I think you need to edit your question to include more detail. I think the issue is somewhere outside of the code that you provided.

Comment: I have updated my code if further code needed plz let me know